# Thingsboard charts

Tags: thingsboard

May i know the reason why the bars in the bar graph of thingsboard is starting halfway after the x axis data date point. For eq, if the data is for october 11, it will be represented halfway after october 11 and the bar ends in halfway after october 12, instead of starting from october 11 and ending just before october 12.
the function is average, and grouping interval is given as 1 day, as i need the value at each day represented.

[image]

Comment: Did you try alignment option in Advanced settings chart widget?